# how to get the th text and set value through data attr for td using jquery

Tags: jquery

Here i had done with this code

```
$('table td').each(function(index, element) {
        var th = $('table tr:first-child th').eq($(this).index()).text();
    $(this).attr('data-title', th);
});
```

my problem is when i use multi table is not working.

```
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>title-1</th>
    <th>title-2</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>ooo</td>
    <td>fds</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>title-3</th>
    <th>title-4</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>ooo</td>
    <td>fds</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

can any one solve this problem, i had give some example code for reference above

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `selector` would run over the `document`, restrict it to the current table,

```
$('table td').each(function(index, element) {
   var th = $(this).closest('table').find('tr:first-child th').eq($(this).index()).text();
   $(this).attr('data-title', th);
});
```

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/83yuxqrL/)

Answer (score 1):

Use DOM traversal based on `$(this)`.

```
var th = $(this).closest("table").find("tr:first-child th").eq($(this).index()).text();
```